# What returns new BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-boot, bcrypt

I have Spring Boot Security app with login form which works  with BCryptPasswordEncoder.

My user has password `100`.

So what I should put as a password in login form - hash of number 100?

like `$2a$12$X.omeLbXLKHzA9Hp5hNY8.Buc0Fuisz6eG0gyizubZPu0l2pgwKM.`?

Comment: What do you mean in *My user has password 100.*? you see that in the database, as a record? in this case, password is whatever hashes to 100.. your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes,  a user has a password like String 100.
So hash of 100 should equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user's password already exists in DB as a hash, just put 100 as a password. Spring Security automatically gets hash of your input and compares it with DB hash.

Comment: OK, and if a user has a password like String `100` for example, what I should put in? A hash of `100`?

Comment: This is wrong. Password, if it's hashed, will be compared to its hash in the database, and not to its literal value.